# Introducing an operator by a bilinear form

Tags: operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $I = (0, 1)$ and $H_0^2 (I)$ the closure of $C_c^\infty (I)$ in $W^{2, 2} (I)$. Consider 
$$a : H_0^2 (I) \times H_0^2 (I) \to \mathbb{R}$$
defined by
$$a(u, v) = \int\limits_I u''(x) v''(x) \, dx.$$
Can someone please give me a hint on how to show that 
$$\{u \in H_0^2(I) : |a(u, v)| \leq c \|v\|_{L^2(I)}, \forall v \in H_0^2(I)\} = H^4(I) \cap H_0^2(I)?$$ (This set is the domain of the introduced operator.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integration by parts and the Riesz representation theorem.

For the one inclusion, if $u\in H^4(I) \cap H^2_0(I)$, we can integrate by parts twice to obtain

$$a(u,v) = \int\limits_I u''(x)v''(x)\,dx = \int\limits_I u^{(4)}(x)v(x)\,dx$$

and see that

$$\lvert a(u,v)\rvert \leqslant \lVert u^{(4)}\rVert_{L^2(I)}\cdot \lVert v\rVert_{L^2(I)}.$$

For the other inclusion, if $u\in H^2_0(I)$ is such that $v\mapsto a(u,v)$ is continuous in the $L^2(I)$-norm, then the Riesz representation theorem asserts the existence of a $w\in L^2(I)$ such that

$$a(u,v) = \int\limits_I w(x)v(x)\,dx$$

for all $v\in H_0^2(I)$. Then it remains to see that $w = u^{(4)}$ (as the distributional derivative). For that, consider $v\in C_c^\infty(I)$ and integrate by parts.

Comment: But why $u ''' \in L^2(I)$? For $u'''$ being in $H^4(I) \cap H_0^2(I)$, we must have $u', u'', u''', u^{(4)} \in L^2(I)$.

Comment: Your target is showing $w = u^{(4)}$. Assuming that is the case, you get $$u'''(x) = c + \int_0^x w(t)\,dt,$$ and the right hand side is easily seen to be in $L^2(I)$. Now drop the assumption, and work with the right hand side (and iterate the procedure) to find that indeed $w = u^{(4)}$.